# Angular JS with factory as a local file with JSON in the file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to modify the following Angular JS example so it works as a standalone file in a folder on a device not connected to the Internet. http://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToAngular/exampleViewer/#/44

I am ok with local-linking the two libraries at the end of the process, and I believe I have referenced the templates correctly. I have made a local array for the JSON data (countriesArray) but I don't know how to load this to the countries factory correctly, and without http. I have used the example's JSON URL temporarily, but there must be another error with the code as it only displays a blank screen.

Sorry for my ignorance.

```html
<html ng-app="countryApp">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Angular.js Example</title>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.10/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', ['ngRoute']);
       var countriesArray = [
      {
        "name": "China",
        "population": 1359821000,
        "flagURL": "//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg",
        "capital": "Beijing",
        "gdp": 12261
      },
      {
        "name": "India",
        "population": 1205625000,
        "flagURL": "//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/41/Flag_of_India.svg",
        "capital": "New Delhi",
        "gdp": 4716
      },
      {
        "name": "United States of America",
        "population": 312247000,
        "flagURL": "//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg",
        "capital": "Washington, D.C.",
        "gdp": 16244
      }
    ];
          countryApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
              when('/', {
                template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="country in countries"><a href="#/{{country.name | encodeURI}}">{{country.name}}</a></li></ul>',
                controller: 'CountryListCtrl'
              }).
              when('/:countryName', {
                template: '<h1>{{country.name}}</h1><ul><li>Flag: <img ng-src="{{country.flagURL}}" width="100"></li><li>Population: {{country.population | number }}</li><li>Capital: {{country.capital}}</li><li>GDP: {{country.gdp | currency }}</li></ul>',
                controller: 'CountryDetailCtrl'
              }).
              otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
              });
          });
    
          countryApp.factory('countries', function(){
            function getData(callback){
              $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToAngular/examples/snapshots/snapshot42/countries.json',
                cache: true
              }).success(callback);
            }
    
            return {
              list: getData,
              find: function(name, callback){
                getData(function(data) {
                  var country = data.filter(function(entry){
                    return entry.name === name;
                  })[0];
                  callback(country);
                });
              }
            };
          });
    
          countryApp.controller('CountryListCtrl', function ($scope, countries){
            countries.list(function(countries) {
              $scope.countries = countries;
            });
          });
    
          countryApp.controller('CountryDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, countries){
            countries.find($routeParams.countryName, function(country) {
              $scope.country = country;
            });
          });
    
          countryApp.filter('encodeURI', function(){
            return window.encodeURI;
          });
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div ng-view>{{countries}}</div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You've forgotten to inject the $http service into the countries factory - most likely reason why it's not working.

`countryApp.factory('countries', function ($http) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your array of countries is best placed in the factory than as a global variable.

Then, in the function `getData` of the factory, instead of making the http call just pass the array to your callback.

The factory looks as follows :

```
countryApp.factory('countries', function () {

    var countriesArray = [ ... ];

    function getData(callback) {
        return callback(countriesArray);
    }

    return {
        list: getData
    };
});
```

**See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/L6ayp289/)**

---

#### Avoid using a callback :

Your previous `getData` function used to pass the result to the callback, and the call from the controller was as follows :

```
countries.list(function (countries) {
    $scope.countries = countries;
});
```

But you can try to avoid using a callback for that and use a *thenable* instead :

1) Inject `$q` as a dependency of your factory

2) Rewrite `getData` as :

```
function getData() {
    return $q.when(countriesArray);
}
```

Note `return $q.when(countriesArray)` might seem a bit tricky if you are not used to. But it's not very difficult. Here we are literally saying *"return when countriesArray is resolved"*. As countries array is not something asynchronous, we can return immediately, and `$q.when` wraps the object into a $q promise, therefore the caller can call `getData` as follows : `getData.then(...)`

3) Now, the call from the controller looks like :

```
countries.list().then(function (countries) {
    $scope.countries = countries;
});
```

**See [second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/L6ayp289/1)**

---

#### Fetch the data from a local json

If you want to load the data from a standalone file instead of putting them right in the factory (that would be a valuable choice), you will have to get back `$http`. You would call a local url, therefore there is absolutely no problem to run that on a device not connected to the internet :

```
 function getData() {
    return $http.get('countries.json');
}
```

`$http` returns a promise, therefore the call to `getData` stay unchanged : `getData.then(...)`

Comment: Thank you Michael for your response. So quick, detailed and educational. I am now trying to find why the list template works but the individual country pages return curly brackets rather than the data, but it's already much further than I could have got in hours alone. Thank you so much.

Comment: That's because I didn't implemented the `find` method in the `countries` factory, as that was a bit over the question.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have tried to add the method back in, and to do so taking into account what you said about avoiding callbacks. I understand methods a bit more now, but I can't get it to work, and think I need to make changes to getData to allow this.

Comment: `filter` returns an array, therefore, with this method you have to return the first. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/L6ayp289/3/).

Comment: You might be interested by some javascript libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs). That is useful especially when you have to work with objects or arrays in js, but not only. For example to find the country named China in the array with lodash would be : `_.findWhere(countriesArray, {name: 'China'})`

Comment: Thanks Michael for solving this. I am very pleased with the result. Additionally I wanted this to work with IE8, and was able to by including a reference to https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim